# Ruby get parent dir of current file

Tags: ruby, spreadsheet, relative-path

I have simple script that should read excel and print two cells:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'ruby-ole','1.2.11.4'
require 'spreadsheet'

class Filter
    # Gets zipcode range
    def get_zipcode_range
        wb = Spreadsheet.open "../data/zipcode_range.xls"
        sheet = wb.worksheet 0
        [sheet.cell(0, 0), sheet.cell(0, 1)]
    end
end

f = Filter.new
puts f.get_zipcode_range
```

File structure is as follows:

```
FilterExcel
  data
    zipcode_range.xls
  lib
    filter.rb
```

When I open command prompt and go to FilterExcel\lib and run:

```
ruby filter.rb
```

It gives expected output:

> 3911AW
>
> 3911ZZ

But when I run script from projects root folder, FilterExcel, then it raises error:

> C:\Documents and Settings\Erik\FilterExcel>ruby lib\filter.rb
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spreadsheet-0.7.4/lib/spreadsheet.rb:68:in
>   'initialize': No such file or directory - ../data/zipcode_range.xls
>   (Errno::ENOENT)
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spreadsheet-0.7.4/lib/spreadsheet.rb:68:in
>   'open'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spreadsheet-0.7.4/lib/spreadsheet.rb:68:in
>   'open'
>           from lib/filter.rb:56:in 'get_zipcode_range'
>           from lib/filter.rb:63:in ''

P.S. I use Windows XP if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `File.expand_path` [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-expand_path):

```
wb = Spreadsheet.open File.expand_path("../data/zipcode_range.xls", __FILE__)
```

Assuming, that the file you posted lies in the same directory as `data/`. If `data/` is in the parent directory of your current Ruby file, go up twice:

```
wb = Spreadsheet.open File.expand_path("../../data/zipcode_range.xls", __FILE__)
```

The first `../` always neutralizes the `__FILE__` when using `File.expand_path` this way. If you are not sure, make a debugging output of the file path that was generated:

```
puts File.expand_path("../data/zipcode_range.xls", __FILE__)
```

Comment: As I wrote in question, called file (filter.rb) doesn't lie in data dir but in lib dir.
`puts File.expand_path("../data/zipcode_range.xls", __FILE__)`, gives: `C:/Documents and Settings/Erik/FilterExcel/lib/data/zipcode_range.xls` which is unexpected result. But `puts File.expand_path("../../data/zipcode_range.xls", __FILE__)` gives correct output: `C:/Documents and Settings/Erik/FilterExcel/data/zipcode_range.xls`.

Answer (score 0):

you should change your code from

```
wb = Spreadsheet.open "../data/zipcode_range.xls"
```

to

```
wb = Spreadsheet.open "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../data/zipcode_range.xls"
```

Comment: It raises error again: `C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spreadsheet-0.7.4/lib/spreadsheet.rb:68:in 'initialize': No such file or directory - lib/../data/zipcode_range.xls (Errno::E
NOENT)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spreadsheet-0.7.4/lib/spreadshe
et.rb:68:in 'open'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spreadsheet-0.7.4/lib/spreadshe
et.rb:68:in 'open'
        from lib/filter.rb:9:in 'get_zipcode_range'
        from lib/filter.rb:16:in '<main>'`